# ERROR at line 3: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle

I am breaking my head to find out where the error is coming from.
Here is my insert statment.

```
INSERT INTO dimension_tab
SELECT
TRUNC(DBMS_RANDOM.value(low = > 1, high => 3)) AS fact_1_id,
TRUNC(DBMS_RANDOM.value(low = > 1, high => 6)) AS fact_2_id,
TRUNC(DBMS_RANDOM.value(low = > 1, high => 11)) AS fact_3_id,
TRUNC(DBMS_RANDOM.value(low = > 1, high => 11)) AS fact_4_id,
ROUND(DBMS_RANDOM.value(low = > 1, high => 100), 2) AS sales_value
FROM dual
CONNECT BY level <= 1000;
```

This is the error which I am getting

```
TRUNC(DBMS_RANDOM.value("low" = > 1, high => 3)) AS fact_1_id,
                          *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

Please tell me where the mistake went.

Comment: Syntax error?  if you're after a number between 1 and 3 shouldn't the syntax be DBMS_RANDOM.value(1,3)?  I'm not sure what you're trying to do with low = > 1 [Oracle link on DBMS_RANDOM](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_random.htm)

Comment: Are you using a version of Oracle prior to 11g?

Comment: yes @xQbert it is a syntax error I think Oracle 10g will not support `=>` anymore

Comment: That's your problem then.  You're using valid syntax, but for a feature that was introduced in 11g.

Answer (score 5):

The operator is `=>`, not `= >`.

Comment: I have tested both same error is repeating

Comment: `TRUNC(DBMS_RANDOM.value(low => 1, high => 3)) AS fact_1_id,
                            *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis`

Comment: Sorry, I only have [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/10662) to test it right now. Of course, you don't really need named parameters here.

Comment: no worries @Alvaro g. vicario I got it. I made a syntax error `TRUNC(DBMS_RANDOM.value(1, 3)) AS fact_1_id,` this worked.

Answer (score 2):

You're misusing DBMS_RANDOM.value with parameters; use

```
TRUNC(DBMS_RANDOM.value(1, 3)) AS fact_1_id,
```

[image: Example]
Took from this [Reference](http://psoug.org/reference/dbms_random.html)

Comment: Thank you @Bigood u are right but i do knw why they kept -1 to your ans. Your advice is helpful